# convert <bean/> code to @Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I'm working on a project in Spring using SpringMVC, i'm using the xml element `<bean/>` and i want to convert my code to `@Bean`

**spring-bean.xml**

```
<bean id="myDao" class="com.my.dao.EmployeImplDB" init-method="init"></bean>

<bean class="com.my.service.EmployeImplMetier" id="myMetier">
    <property name="dao" ref="myDao"></property>
</bean>
```

how to convert xml to annotation `@Bean`?

Comment: create method named `myMetier` put `@Bean` method on it.

Comment: how? PLZ an example i'm beginner in Spring

Answer (score 1):

You can write this way

```
@Repository
class EmployeImplDB{}


@Service   
EmployeImplMetier{

@Autowired
EmployeImplDB myDao;

}
```

@Repository signifies that your bean is a DAO class

@Autowire**d** injects dao class EmployeImplDB in the Service class

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
@Bean(name = "myDao", initMethod = "init")
public EmployeDao myDao() {
    EmployeDao eidb = new EmployeImplDB();
    return eidb;
}

@Bean(name = "myMetier")
public Metier employeImplDB(EmployeDao myDao) {
    Metier metier= new EmployeImplMetier(myDao);
    return metier;
}
```

Note: Presuming that name of `EmployeImplDB` superclass (interface) is EmployeeDB.

Comment: is it like this?

**com/my/Dao/EmployeImplDB.java**
`@Bean(name = "myDao", initMethod = "init")
public class EmployeImplDB implements EmployeDao {
 //my code ...
}
`
**com/my/service/EmployeImplMetier.java**
`@Bean(name = "myMetier")
public class EmployeImplMetier extends Metier{
 //my code ..
}
`

Comment: In some class which is annotated with `@Configuration` annotation.